# How to display base64 image in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Need help again ;)

I would like to show a photo in my Angular page. These are my steps,

1. REST API gets a document/record from backend MongoDB. The base64 images are stored as this.

[image]

2. The images/data are loaded into an array {{file_src[i]}} in the component code, then the component HTML will show the image as below

[image]

Situations:

1. If I used "img srcs={{file_src[i]}}", I got insecure operation. My REST API server has CORS enabled. Since the image is base64 data and doesn't have any URL, I don't know it is related to CORS.

[image]

2. I googled around and found the ng-src and data-ng-src directives. Both of them don't work too. Please see my binding error below.

[image]

Question: how to show the base64 image in my Angular page?

------Code as requested by Vic--------

```
<section class="fhirForm">
        <fieldset>
            <legend class="hd">
                <span class="text">Photo</span>
            </legend>
            <div class="bd" formArrayName="photos">
                <div *ngFor="let photo of patFormGroup.controls.photos.controls; let i=index" class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body" [formGroupName]="i">

                        <label>Description</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="desc">

                        <label>Photo</label>
                        <input type="file" size="30" multiple formControlName="photo" name="crud8" (change)="photoChange(input, i)" #input>
                        <!-- img src={{file_srcs[i]}} crossorigin="anonymous" alt="" /-->
                        <img data-ng-src={{file_srcs[i]}} alt="" />

                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right" *ngIf="patFormGroup.controls.photos.controls.length > 1" (click)="removePhoto(i)"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>

        <div class="margin-20">
            <a (click)="addPhoto()" style="cursor: default">
                <small>Add another photo +</small>
            </a>
        </div>
    </section>
```

---

```
  initPhoto(desc?: String, photo?: string) {
    //Add new entry on the 1 dimensional array. Allow 1 photo per section
    this.file_srcs.push(photo);
    console.log("Photo for file_srcs: [" + this.file_srcs[this.file_srcs.length - 1] + "]");

    return this.formBuilder.group({
      desc: [desc],
      photo: [photo]
    });
  }
```

Please see the console.log. It showed that this.file_srcs are valid.

[image]

------------- Error Message in Chrome -------

[image]

------------- UPDATE 1 -----------

If I commented out the "input type=file ..." line above the "img src" as below, I can see the photo. What's wrong with my input? Sorry, I don't remember what is that #input for.

Hence, my issue may not be in the photo, but on the input line ;) Shame on me!!!

```
                <label>Photo</label>
                <!-- input type="file" size="30" formControlName="photo" name="crud8" (change)="photoChange(input, i)" #input -->
                <img src={{file_srcs[i]}} crossorigin="anonymous" alt="" />
```

[image]

--------- RESOLVED -----------

Thanks a lot for all the help!!!

i. the base64 image isn't the root cause;

ii. the file input "input type=file" was initialized by incorrect supplying the base64 image as the default value. It caused the error - failed to set the value of HtmlInputElement is correct in IE. The error message 'Insecure Operation' may be misleading in Firefox.

Hence, the root cause is not related to the base64 image. I would like to delete this thread a week later.

```
initPhoto(desc?: String, photo?: string) {

this.file_srcs.push(photo);
console.log("Photo for file_srcs[" + (this.file_srcs.length - 1) + "]: [" + this.file_srcs[this.file_srcs.length - 1] + "]");

return this.formBuilder.group({
  desc: [desc],
  photo: [""]     //This was photo: [photo]. After supplying the default value as "", it works well.
});
```

Best regards,

Autorun

Comment: Share your code for this, how you are fetching image from server?

Answer (score 2):

Fetch the base64 content in your controller like this:

```
$http.get($scope.user.photo).then(function(response) {
    $scope.user.data = response.data;
});
```

then display it on view

```
<img data-ng-src="data:image/png;base64,{{user.data}}"/>
```

Comment: Hi Vic, thx a lot! if I use "data-ng-src", I got this error --> Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'ng-src' since it isn't a known property of 'img'.

Comment: @Autorun can you share your code? I commented the same on your question also

Comment: Hi Vic, thanks again. Yes, I could share my code. Since there are a lot of code, how can I share? Here is just a tiny portion. Please see the code above.

Answer (score 0):

I use base64 image a lot and haven't see that error before. Is it caused by the `crossorigin` attribute?

```js
angular.module('test', []).controller('Test', Test);

function Test($scope) {
  $scope.base64 = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA8AAAAOCAYAAADwikbvAAAA+0lEQVQ4T6WS3W3CMBSFz40QvDJCu0GYALJB2QBeUFzjCm9AJ0gLMQl9STegG5QNYARG6CsI+SKjpmppSY3w8/10fnwIVzy6lE2SollrbBcAPV8ET2fzOzAXDNYPUrx6wxOT9QjkwL4DnWMvODV5wUAP4EclxbiM+i88meUJMUYA3pSMu987qoRLqwDW+10j0rr/4QV/lrNwxwGClpSD9enPHJXTdD5i4vY+YK2F2BjzElrYdwDN05x/KpelMOGJGB0AIQGboYxvz23hR+apyVcO+jq2HCklll7wcT31rbMbgrBU93FUtcBfbSdZdlOztILlbpWq90jOqR8Au8VfIQFLZecAAAAASUVORK5CYII=";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='test' ng-controller='Test'>
  <img src={{base64}} />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks lcycool. Even though I removed the crossorigin attribute, I got the same insecure operation error.